# NodeJs Use Multer as a middleware to parse files and conditionally initiate storage

Tags: node.js, express, next.js, file-upload, multer

I'm using `NextJS` endpoint to receive `fromData` with file/files

I need to parse the file's data and use metadata to decide the file name in the `Multer` storage.

For example, based on the file name, I would like to create an entry in the DB for Users "profile" and use that Entry ID for the file path in Multer storage (Upladoing to GCP bucket)

What I need is a way for Multer to let me have access to the file data before initiating the storage object - in which I need to provide the file's `destination` before it's known to me.

I tried:

1. Creating two `Multer` middlewares, the first one has no storage object configured, and the second one has it.

- Problem: I'm getting the error `"multer Unexpected end of form"` when the data is going out to the remote destination. - seems like it was ruining its own file parsing

2. Using `Multer` alongside `formidable`

- Problem: formidable with hoog the files from the response, and I started going down the rabbit hall of manually adding the `files` key to the `req` object so Mulert could upload it. But `Multer` kept overwriting it with an empty array

3. Tinkering a bit with the callback function from the destination, but it seems like I can't have the `string` calculated at the time of upload, just at initialization

Solutions in Express.JS will be easily understood if you have a solution, not for Next.Js I'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might be stuck with a similar issue.
I can't recommend adding using a combination of middlewares to process the form data.

But something that worked for me is to send the data I needed in the request's query string.

It ain't pretty, but it works and saves a lot of time to find another way to submit the file's data